# Get Current User in django-filter Method

Tags: python, django

I have a filter where I need to access the `request.user`. However, django-filter does not pass it. Without using the messy `inspect.stack()` is there a way to get the current user in the method `member_filter` below?

```
class ClubFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    member = django_filters.MethodFilter(action='member_filter')

    class Meta:
        model = Club
        fields = ['member']

    def member_filter(self, queryset, value):
        # get current user here so I can filter on it.
        return queryset.filter(user=???)
```

For example this works but feels wrong...

```
def member_filter(self, queryset, value):
        import inspect
        request_user = None
        for frame_record in inspect.stack():
            if frame_record[3] == 'get_response':
                request_user = frame_record[0].f_locals['request'].user
                print(request_user)
```

is there maybe a way to add this to some middleware that injects user into all methods? Or is there a better way?

Comment: When do you instantiate `ClubFilter`? Is the request user known at that point in time? If so: pass the user as a parameter to `__init__()` and then on to the filter function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do it, and it's very easy.

First, define `__init__` method in your `ClubFilter` class that will take one extra argument:

```
class ClubFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    # ...

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(ClubFilter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

With having your user saved into attribute inside `ClubFilter`, you can use it in your filter. Just remember to pass current user from your view inside `FilterSet`.

Comment: You can't pass arguments to `FilterSet`, you don't initialize it unless you inherit from `BaseFilterBackend` or `DjangoFilterBackend` and reimplement the `filter_queryset` method which initializes the `FilterSet`. So this method doesn't work unless you override `filter_queryset` in a custom FilterBackend.

Comment: @Sassan you're talking about using `django-filters` in `djangorestframework`, which is not the case from question above. But it's just a matter of creating your own filter backend, as you said. Feel free to edit my answer and add case when using `djangorestframework`, if you think it's necessary.

Comment: If using `djangorestframework`, you can do the filtering against the user in the rest framework view class, like described here: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-the-current-user

Answer (score 1):

Try `self.request.user`.

[Why it must work.](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/blob/2.0dev1/django_filters/views.py#L45)

Comment: This worked for me! `return queryset.filter(members__employee=self.request.user)`

Answer (score 0):

you can access the request instance in FilterSet.qs property, and then filter the primary queryset there.

```
class ClubFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
member = django_filters.MethodFilter(action='member_filter')

class Meta:
    model = Club
    fields = ['member']

    @property
    def qs(self):
        primary_queryset=super(ClubFilter, self).qs
        return primary_queryset.filter(user=request.user)
```